# Will MR overwrite records if I use the same directory for input and output?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to filter out obsolete records and add new records during a MR run. I plan to write a mapper that will read in records from a temp directory (new input) and a repository directory (previous results). When the mapper runs it will ingest the new with the old. If the mapper only writes out records with a timestamp less than 30 days old lets say, and I also use the repository directory for output, will the new results overwrite the old results, effectively adding new content and deleting obsolete content? I'm using the Apache libraries with Java 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

It will throw an error. Hadoop does not output to existing directories. It always creates the directory. So, the output directory must not exist. If it does, it will throw an error. I am assuming you are using the standard `FileOutputFormat` or some extension of it.